# angularjs scope variable change onclick for conditional div

Tags: angularjs

i have two divs i want to show them conditionally with onclick event .

my-angular-app.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#showless', function(el) {
 var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myapp]');
 var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
  $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.value = false;
    });

});

$(document).on('click', '#showmore', function(el) {
  var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myapp]');
  var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
  $scope.$apply(function() {
       $scope.value = true;
 });

});
```

and my div of myapp (myapp.html)

```
    <div ng-show="desc" id="description" class="text-muted" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;color:#2E2E2E;font-size:11px;">{{myapp.value|truncate}}<span><a id="showmore" href="">more</a></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!desc" id="description" class="text-muted" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;color:#2E2E2E;font-size:11px;">{{myapp.value}}<span><a id="showless" href="">less</a></span>
    </div>
```

(truncate is a filter i wrote which works fine .)

Comment: Looks like you're coming from jquery. Angular allows you to bind "ng-click", so you can do something like ng-click=toggle(), and in your JS code just have a toggle() function that changes the state of the desc variable.

Comment: i am using it for chrome extension that does not allows inline scripts which means  ng-click=toggle() is not allowed .

Comment: `ng-click` is not an inline script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but Angular provides `ng-click`, so you should not have to bind to `$(document).on('click')`.

I'd suggest a simpler approach for conditional show:

```
<div ng-show="desc" id="description" class="text-muted" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;color:#2E2E2E;font-size:11px;">{{myapp.value|truncate}}<span><a id="showmore" ng-click="desc = true" href="#">more</a></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!desc" id="description" class="text-muted" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;color:#2E2E2E;font-size:11px;">{{myapp.value}}<span><a id="showless" ng-click="desc = false" href="#">less</a></span>
    </div>
```

The above uses `ng-click` to set the value of `desc`.  Therefore, you don't need any other logic in the controller to toggle the `divs`.

Comment: objective is to toggle desc , by <a id="showmore" href="">more</a> and <a id="showless" href="">less</a> like u have generally to show and hide large text . hope i am clear . thanks ..

Comment: Updated.  I moved the `ng-click` to the `a`.